# Return 401 status code for 302 redirect in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to return 401 from my ASP.NET MVC controller but it always returns 302.

I tried the solutions provided in various forums but none seems to be working for me.

AccountController.cs

```
[RequiresAuthentication]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = "")
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError<LoginViewModel, string>(m => m.UserName, Messages.Login_AuthenticationFailed);
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
}

public class RequiresAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Server.TransferRequest("/Account/Login/?NOT_AUTHORISED=TRUE", false);
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        MiniProfiler.Stop();
        var context = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);

        //if(FormsAuthentication.IsEnabled && context.Response.StatusCode == 302)
        //{
            //context.Response.Clear();
            //context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        //}

        if (Request["NOT_AUTHORISED"] == "TRUE" && Response.StatusCode != (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        {
           Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
           Response.Clear();
           Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
           var url = Request.UrlReferrer?.PathAndQuery ?? "/";
           var query = "?ReturnUrl=" + url;
           Response.RedirectLocation = query;
           Response.End();
        }
}
```

Login.chtml

```
    @Html.ResponsiveTextControlFor(m => m.UserName, inputLayout: Constants.UserInterface.LayoutOneColumnInput)
    
    @Html.ResponsiveTextControlFor(m => m.Password, inputLayout: Constants.UserInterface.LayoutOneColumnInput, isPasswordControl: true)
    
    using (Html.BeginSection(Constants.UserInterface.LayoutItem))
    {
        using (Html.BeginSection(Constants.UserInterface.LayoutButton))
        {
            @Html.SubmitButton("Log In")
        }
    }
```

Any help about this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: experts need your inputs please

Comment: Do you want to redirect or return 401? Choose one

Comment: i want to return 401 but looks like .net framework redirects to Login if 401 is returned as response code

Comment: @sajeshNambiar Were you able to handle this scenario? I want to do the same thing. :)